# NumberFormatter() doesn't force decimal place

Tags: ios, swift, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

Here is my code:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber {
func getFormattedDecimalString() -> String {
    let numberFormatter            = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    numberFormatter.numberStyle    = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    if let decimalString = numberFormatter.string(from: self) {
        return decimalString
    } else {
        return ""
    }
}
}
```

If I have the number 4.11, it shows 4.11. If I have the number 4.1, it shows 4.1. If I have the number 4, it shows 4. I want it to show 4.11, 4.10 and 4.00. I thought this is what minimumFractionDigits was for. I've also tried adding the line `numberFormatter.alwaysShowsDecimalSeparator = true` and this does nothing.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: In numberFormatter.string(from: self) what self is indicating because can not reproduce your problem. its working fine for me

Comment: @AkBombe It's an extension of NSDecimalNumber (I edited my post). I put it in a regular function and it worked, but this doesn't work. I get the NSDecimalNumber from core data.

Comment: `NSDecimalNumber(string: "4.0").getFormattedDecimalString()` gives `4.00` in my test. Please show a concrete reproducible example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: are you storing it in string format? either

Comment: either store your results in string format or format while displaying.

Comment: Is it possible you have another extension on `NSNumber` or other numeric type called `getFormattedDecimalString`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was actually caused by unrelated mistake I had made: I had two ViewControllers and I was editing the wrong one. The one that had the incorrect code was the one attached to the view.